# rss feed in EBSCO igoogle

Tags: rss, igoogle

I am setting up RSS feeds for searches and journal alerts from the EBSCO
 database in iGoogle. The widget only allows three results on my iGoogle page 
but I might have 10 or 12 articles or results that should be fed into the spot.
EBSCO said I had to edit the html code to a number larger than 3. However, 
the code is lengthy and I don't seem to find a number three to edit.
Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0):

The basic gadget that google provide by default displays only the latest 3 items.  There is a preference that every user has to display up to 9 entries, but we leave this up to the user to decide.

It is relatively easy for you to develop your own gadget that display your RSS feed with more items.